# Im making a discord bot in discord.py and im getting a invalid syntax error and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: discord, discord.py

Here is my main embed code

```
embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Hello, and welcome to Alex's Bobux", description="Desc", color=#00ff00)
      embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
      embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

and this is the error im getting

```
File "main.py", line 21
    embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

any help is most greatly appreciated, but for now thats my issue.
EDIT: ITS SOMETHING TO DO WITH PYTHON NOT TAKING MY HEX CODES, how do i fix it lol?

Comment: i just figured out its something to do with the color, for some reason hex codes wont work/

Comment: Try putting the hex code in quotes, like `color='#00ff00'`

Comment: Use `0x00ff00`. The color should be an integer or `discord.Color`

Answer (score 1):

Your color was `color=#...`.

The moment there is a `#`, it is considered to be a comment (as per your code) and that's why you have an invalid syntax error.

#### Solution:

Put the same within a String (`color='#00ff00'`) or use `0x` instead of `#` (`color=0x00ff00`)